# Clone to smaller hard drive with less data than smaller hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone, migration

How do I clone the data (not the partition) from a larger drive to a smaller drive? I need this to run in Windows 7 64 Bit, not a bootable live CD/DVD and I need a freeware or open source program. I do own a copy of Paragon Hard Disk Manager though it (along with Acronis Migrate Easy trial) complains about the partition size instead of just copying data.

Comment: If you need only data, a standard Windows copy will do the job, or you can use `xcopy` from the command line.

Comment: @AFH It doesn't, a basic copy will get 5% the way through and it will ask Yes to all twice, hit an error and I have no idea what copied or didn't which I would then do a cut/paste. That is why I need a tool to `clone the data`.

Comment: "cloning" does not copy files, it is done at a lower level and copies sectors of a hard drive. If all you want to do is "copy" files then use xcopy as AFH mentions, or robocopy with :MIR   You can can not clone to smaller hard drive, nor clone any HD that is mounted

Comment: @John if the copy stops, then the file is probably open or in use. Use RoboCopy, if you want details as to what got copied and errors. Use a LiveCD to get past an Open or InUse file if you have no idea what file is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned the idea of directly doing a reliable copy because while I try to leave reasonable answers behind for other people who will eventually encounter the issue sometimes the lack of time (say, dozens of hours) are simply not available to tackle a common problem no one bothered to resolve.

For me this worked however it may not work for everyone. I don't like expensive or cheap solutions, I like them affordable; this answer is unfortunately cheap but it works. I used my copy of Paragon Hard Disk Manager to reduce the size of the partition to be smaller than the target hard drive and *then* did a partition copy.

Comment: You can also use [GParted Live CD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/) to adjust partition size and use [CloneZilla Live CD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/files/clonezilla_live_stable/) to clone partitions. All the two distributions are free, however they are using linux, but they support NTFS filesystem. I've used these two utilities to shrink Windows 8 Restore partition and clone it to a smaller partitions.